# SKLearn Error with Pipeline and Gridsearch

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I would like to first split my data in a test and train set. Then I want to use GridSearchCV on my training set (internally split into train/validation set). In the end I want to collect all the testdata and do some other things (not in the scope of the question).

I have to scale my data. So I want to handle this problem in a pipeline. Some things in my SVC should be ficed (kernel='rbf', class_weight=...).
When I run the code the following occurs:

"ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator Pipeline"

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried to follow this thread: [StandardScaler with Pipelines and GridSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252156/standardscaler-with-pipelines-and-gridsearchcv)

The only difference is, that I fix some parameters in my SVC. How can I handle this?

```
target = np.array(target).ravel()
loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.get_n_splits(input)
    # Outer Loop
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(input):    
        X_train, X_test = input[train_index], input[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = target[train_index], target[test_index]
        p_grid = {'estimator__C': np.logspace(-5, 2, 20),}
                  'estimator__gamma': np.logspace(-5, 3, 20)}

        SVC_Kernel = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced',tol=10e-4, max_iter=200000, probability=False)
        pipe_SVC = Pipeline([('scaler',  RobustScaler()),('SVC', SVC_Kernel)])  
        n_splits = 5
        scoring = "f1_micro"

        inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits,
                         shuffle=True, random_state=5)
        clfSearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_SVC, param_grid=p_grid,
                                 cv=inner_cv, scoring='f1_micro', iid=False, n_jobs=-1)

        clfSearch.fit(X_train, y_train)



        print("Best parameters set found on validation set for Support Vector Machine:")
        print()
        print(clfSearch.best_params_)
        print()
        print(clfSearch.best_score_)
        print("Grid scores on validation set:")
        print()
```

I also tried it this way:

```
p_grid = {'estimator__C': np.logspace(-5, 2, 20),
              'estimator__gamma': np.logspace(-5, 3, 20),
              'estimator__tol': [10e-4],
              'estimator__kernel': ['rbf'],
              'estimator__class_weight': ['balanced'],
              'estimator__max_iter':[200000],
              'estimator__probability': [False]}

SVC_Kernel = SVC()
```

This also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `p_grid`. You are grid searching on your `Pipeline`, and that doesn't have anything called `estimator`. It does have something called `SVC`, so if you want to set that `SVC`'s parameter, you should prefix you keys with `SVC__` instead of `estimator__`. So replace `p_grid` with:

```
p_grid = {'SVC__C': np.logspace(-5, 2, 20),}
          'SVC__gamma': np.logspace(-5, 3, 20)}
```

Also, you can replace your outer `for` loop using `cross_validate` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for the tip with Cross validate.